# Oracle SQL grouping error with case statements

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case

I need to calculate some values dynamically based on a filter, which is going to be set in a different application.

But I cannot get the my query to work.

If I use the following code, I get the `ORA-00937 "not a single-group group function"` Error:

```
SELECT
--Dimensions:
  --VALUES_FOR_TABLEAU_METADATA:
    SHIFT_UUID,
--Measures (KPI's):
  --Count:
    SUM(COUNT_IO),
    SUM(COUNT_TARGET_OEE),
  --OEE:
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN TIME_IO = 0 
        OR TIME_TARGET_OEE_100 = 0
        THEN NULL 
        ELSE SUM(TIME_IO)*100/SUM(TIME_TARGET_OEE_100) END) AS OEE,
  --POT:
    SUM(TIME_TARGET_OEE_100_FILTERED)
FROM VALUES_FOR_TABLEAU_METADATA
WHERE
  COUNT_TARGET_OEE != 0
GROUP BY SHIFT_UUID
```

This would implement, that I am missing some values for the `GROUP BY` but I cant figure out which.

Also I tried what happens when I execute the query without the `GROUP BY`, then I get the `ORA-00978 "nested group function without GROUP BY"` Error which would mean that I need to add a value which the `CASE` statement can be grouped by. But the query with the values from the `CASE` also in the `GROUP BY` gave me the `ORA-00937` again.

I also thought about doing a nested request but I am not sure if the request could still be dynamic then.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: please give complete error text

Comment: @HasanFathi updated the errors

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the below case statements in Group by :

FPY
FTY
for
pr

Include them in group by..or else use separate subquery for those case statements.

Comment: So I tried something like this before:

`GROUP BY SHIFT_UUID, OEE` gives `ORA-00904 "%s: invalid identifier"`

`GROUP BY SHIFT_UUID, (CASE 
        WHEN TIME_IO = 0 
        OR TIME_TARGET_OEE_100 = 0
        THEN NULL 
        ELSE SUM(TIME_IO)*100/SUM(TIME_TARGET_OEE_100) END)` gives `ORA-00934 "group function is not allowed here"`(which makes sense...)

and `GROUP BY SHIFT_UUID, TIME_IO, TIME_TARGET_OEE_100` gives the `ORA-00937`again

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the nested `SUM()` calls, but you don't seem to need them:

```
SELECT
--Dimensions:
  --VALUES_FOR_TABLEAU_METADATA:
    SHIFT_UUID,
--Measures (KPI's):
  --Count:
    SUM(COUNT_IO),
    SUM(COUNT_TARGET_OEE),
  --OEE:
    100 * SUM(CASE 
        WHEN TIME_IO = 0 
        OR TIME_TARGET_OEE_100 = 0
        THEN 0 
        ELSE TIME_IO/TIME_TARGET_OEE_100 END) AS OEE,
  --POT:
    SUM(TIME_TARGET_OEE_100_FILTERED)
FROM VALUES_FOR_TABLEAU_METADATA
WHERE
  COUNT_TARGET_OEE != 0
GROUP BY SHIFT_UUID
```

I've moved the `100 *` outside the `SUM()`, and made the `ELSE` expression just divide the two values for that row. I've also changed `THEN NULL` to `THEN 0` as having any null values will make the entire sum null; perhaps that's what you want but you only seem to need/want to skip those that would cause a divide-by-zero error. (Excluding `TIME_IO = 0` isn't really necessary either as that won't error).